# how to emit value from built flow object

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

My question is that how we can emit a value from a built flow object like this:

```
class Sample {
    var flow: Flow<Object> = null

    fun sendRequest(){
       flow = flow{}
       requestWrapper.flowResponse = flow

    }

    fun getResponse(){
       // I want to emit data here with built flow object on 
       // requestWrapper like this

        requestWrapper.flowResponse.emit()

    }
}
```

is any possible solution for this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `MutableSharedFlow` to emit values like in your case:

```
class Sample {
    var flow: MutableSharedFlow<Object>? = MutableSharedFlow(...)

    fun sendRequest(){
       requestWrapper.flowResponse = flow
    }

    fun getResponse(){
       // I want to emit data here with built flow object on 
       // requestWrapper like this

        requestWrapper.flowResponse?.tryEmit(...)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer helped me. but in another class that I collect, it collects data but does not goes to the next line.

Comment: Probably because a new flow is being created each time `sendRequest` is called. Existing collectors will still be collecting from the old flow.

Comment: Right, maybe no need to create an instance of the flow each request. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @BigSt your first answer was correct. I want to have an individual flow object for each requestWrapper object. I solved my issue with takeWhile operator before collecting the response. This approach helped me to cancel the collect and go to the next line.